# convert list of values from a txt file to dictionary

Tags: python, list, file-io, dictionary, readfile

So i have this txt file called "Students.txt", I want to define a function called load(student)
so i have this code:

```
def load(student):
      body
```

im not quite sure what to write for the body of code so that it reads the file and returns the value from the file as dictionary. I know it would be something like readlines()
anyway, the file students.txt looks like this:

```
P883, Michael Smith, 1991
L672, Jane Collins, 1992
(added)L322, Randy Green, 1992
H732, Justin Wood, 1995(added)
^key  ^name        ^year of birth
```

the function has to return as a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{'P883': ('Michael Smith',1991),
'(key)':('name','year')}
```

I managed to return the values by trial and error however i cant make new lines and keep returning \n.

===============
this question has been answered and i used the following code which works perfectly however when there is a space in the values from the txt file.. (see added parts) it doesnt work anymore and gives an error saying that list index is out of range

Comment: Do you have the problem using the `csv` module too? What is the difference between the added data and the original? I don't see any...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it, I think:

```
students = {}

infile = open("students.txt")
for line in infile:
  line = line.strip()
  parts = [p.strip() for p in line.split(",")]
  students[parts[0]] = (parts[1], parts[2])
```

This might not be 100%, but should give you a starting-point. Error handling was omitted for brevity.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a CSV file. You can use the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module then:

```
import csv
studentReader = csv.reader(open('Students.txt', 'rb'), delimiter=',', skipinitialspace=True)
d = dict()
for row in studentReader:
    d[row[0]] = tuple(row[1:])
```

This won't give you the year as integer, you have to transform it yourself:

```
for row in studentReader:
    d[row[0]] = tuple(row[1], int(row[2]))
```

Comment: +1 for being the only person to mention CSV. However you've put CVS instead of CSV in some cases.

Comment: you can remove the leading whitespaces via the reader: `csv.reader(open('students.txt'), delimiter=',', skipinitialspace=True)`

Comment: @juanchopanza: Thank you :) I figured that out too, but I would have been faster if I read your comment ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
def load(students_file):
    result = {}
    for line in students_file:
        key, name, year_of_birth = [x.strip() for x in line.split(",")]
        result[key] = (name, year_of_birth)
    return result
```

Comment: If you `.split(',')`, then `.strip()` each element to remove whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [pickle](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/pickle.html) module in python to save your data as a dict so you could load it easily by unpickling it. Or, you could just do:

```
d = {}
with open('Students.txt', 'r') as f:
  for line in f:
    tmp = line.strip().split(',')
    d[tmp[0]] = tuple(tmp[1],tmp[2])
```