# How to check a string for emptyness or length zero

Tags: python, dictionary, split, strip

I recently asked a question about converting list of values from txt file to dictionary list. You can see it from the link here: [See my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472238/convert-list-of-values-from-a-txt-file-to-dictionary?)

```
P883, Michael Smith, 1991

L672, Jane Collins, 1992

(added)
(empty line here)

L322, Randy Green, 1992

H732, Justin Wood, 1995(/added)

^key    ^name        ^year of birth
```

===============
this question has been answered and i used the following code (accepted answer) which works perfectly:

```
def load(filename):
         students = {}
```

```
   infile = open(filename)
   for line in infile:
       line = line.strip()
       parts = [p.strip() for p in line.split(",")]
       students[parts[0]] = (parts[1], parts[2])
   return students
```

however when there is a line space in the values from the txt file.. (see added parts) it doesnt work anymore and gives an error saying that list index is out of range.

Comment: asking for checking a string for length > 0 or a check on non-empty is really poor - -1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check for empty lines inside your for-loop and skip them:

```
for line in infile:
    line = line.strip()
    if not line:
        continue
    parts = [p.strip() for p in line.split(",")]
    students[parts[0]] = (parts[1], parts[2])
```

Comment: @MarkLakewood I think this assumes line is a string

Comment: @yuf: No need to assume this -- since `infile` is a file in the OP's code, `line` must be a string.

Answer (score 0):

It's really straight forward to check the line for emptyness or length 0:

```
for line in infile:
    line = line.strip()
    if line:
       do_something()

    # or

    if len(line) > 0:
        do_something()
```

Comment: im sorry, im a beginner and still do not know most of the basic codes

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = [line.split(', ') for line in file if line]
result = dict([(list[0], element_list[1:]) for line in lines if line])
```

Answer (score -1):

Check for an empty line by either counting the elements of `parts` (if there are zero (or, in general, less than three) elements in `parts`, the line was empty or at least invalid). or by checking the trimmed value of `line` against the empty string. (Sorry, I can't code Python, so no code sample here...)

**Remember: You should *always* check the size of a dynamically created array before indexing it.**